# Having some quirks with Everyone/Just Me option in MSI installer

Tags: .net, excel, windows-installer, vsto

Can anyone explain in detail what the differences between the following two options in MSI installer are, `Everyone` and `Just Me`? Is `Just Me` always better than 'Everyone'?

In my case here, for some reason, the client seems to be facing some quirks with excel plugin installer. They can only use `Just Me` option to be able to run the plugin correctly. If they choose `Everyone` option, some function of the plugin will not work properly.

By the way this is a VSTO excel 2010 addin and I use VS2010 setup project to create MSI installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both install types have their advantages. What I suspect is the problem in your case is with the add-in registration. The usual deployment method for Office add-in is a per-user install. A per-machine install is possible too, but with a little more settings. Here are some articles to help you:

1. [First article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mshneer/archive/2007/09/04/deploying-your-vsto-add-in-to-all-users-part-i.aspx)
2. [Second article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mshneer/archive/2007/09/05/deploying-your-vsto-add-in-to-all-users-part-ii.aspx)
3. [Third article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mshneer/archive/2008/04/24/deploying-your-vsto-add-in-to-all-users-part-iii.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I've blogged extensively about VSTO AddIns and written many myself.  They are more complicated then what VDPROJ can handle. Also realize that VDPROJ is being phased out and Microsoft recommends the free InstallShield Limited Edition instead.

If you are interested in swtiching over, I have a template project that allows me to create a fully functional VSTO AddIn installer in about one hours time.  It comes with all the plumbing to handle the prereq stack and just takes a few tweaks for the specifics of your VSTO file.  It does require that your VSTO but digitally signed by the likes of Verisign, Comodo et al due to the nature of AddIns.

If you are only VSTO and want Per-User then don't bother with MSI, just use ClickOnce.  But if you want the rich Per-Machine experience you must use MSI as ClickOnce can't do it.